# How make badgets of left in table row in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2, vue-component

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/C_h_e_r_r_y/es3v1jyp/6/) is jsfiddle example which lokks like that:

**HTML**

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.9.1/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
    <el-table
      :data="tableData"
      style="width: 100%">
      <el-table-column
        prop="date"
        label="Date"
        width="180">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column
        prop="name"
        label="Name"
        width="180">
        <el-badge :value="10" class="item" >
           <el-button size="mini">Comments</el-button>
           </el-badge>
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column
        prop="address"
        label="Address">
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </template>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.9.1/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");

.el-table .cell {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

**JS**

var Main = {
      data() {
        return {
          tableData: [{
            date: '2016-05-03',
            name: 'Tom',
            address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
          }, {
            date: '2016-05-02',
            name: 'Tom',
            address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
          }, {
            date: '2016-05-04',
            name: 'Tom',
            address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
          }, {
            date: '2016-05-01',
            name: 'Tom',
            address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
          }]
        }
      }
    }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')

[image: table]

Every badget is placed after comment button. Is there a way to make it on the left?

Answer (score 0):

The badge has been absolutely positioned to `right`. Add this CSS in your stylesheet to position it on the left side.

```
.el-badge__content.is-fixed{
  left: -10px;
  right: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: I'd appreciate if you mark this as an accepted answer if it helped you achieve what you wanted.